# In Azure logic app how we can validate whether any field is present in json body

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my logic I am expecting following json structure.

```
{
    "id": "233343344",
    "eventSourceId": 124443,
    "eventSourceUuid": "3655444",
    "eventTime": "1323",
    "notificationTime": "2333232",
    "eventType": "appointment-reminder-add",
    "notificationType": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "transportParameters": [
        {
            "emailTransportParameters": {
                "version": 1,
                "toAddress": "abc@gmail.com",
                "fromAddress": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "fromName": "test",
                "templateId": "1233",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "type": "aa",
                        "name": "bb",
                        "value": "ccc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

couple of fields  are  required if it is not present I need to take some other action.
How can I validate whether field is present or not and it is not empty  in azure logic app?

```
//pseudo-code 
if(eventSourceId !=null && eventSourceId.length >0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a test with the `coalesce` function, something like the following (here i'm assuming your data is sent in a http trigger

`equals(coalesce(triggerBody()?['eventSourceId'],'EMPTY'),'EMPTY')`

This will return true when the eventSourceId is not present, if eventSourceId can contain EMPTY then it is obviously not a good choice to test against.

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution**

`if(equals(null,<field that you want to check>),false,true)`

And then you can add a condition for true and false and add your actions accordingly !